# Java long is calculated wrongly

Tags: android, long-integer

Consider this piece of code:

```
            // calculate age of dog
            long interval = 1000*60*60*24*30;
            int ageInWeeks  = Weeks.weeksBetween(geburtsDatumDateTime, nowDateTime).getWeeks();
            if (ageInWeeks < 20){
                // wöchentlich
                interval = 1000*60*60*24*7;
            } else if (ageInWeeks >= 20 && ageInWeeks < 52){
                // 2-wöchentlich
                interval = 1000*60*60*24*14;
            } else if (ageInWeeks >= 52){
                // monatlich
                interval = 1000*60*60*24*30;
            }
```

The debugger shows, that in case of ageInWeeks >= 52 the interval is: -1702967296, but it should be: 2592000000

The minus sign suggests some kind of overflow error.
However the maximum value of a long in Java is 2E63-1 which is: 9.2233E18

What I am missing here? Is an Android maximum value for a long smaller?

Comment: you can check the max value of long by typing `Long.MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're computing 32-bit signed ints, the computation overflows, and then you assign the result to a long.

Do your calculation in 64 bits by making one of the operands a long. For example, add `L` to one of the operands to make it a long literal:

```
interval = 1000L*60*60*24*30;
```

Comment: Shouldn't he do the left-most number as `long`, because the integer multiplication could overflow before it gets to the `30L`?

Comment: Doesn't matter in this case but generally makes more sense that way, thanks.

Comment: @laalto Exactly as you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As laalto said, adding a 'L' should make it work.
However, for avoiding these kind of errors in the future, you could use the TimeUnit class (available in Android SDK):

> long interval = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(30);